# Saving answers to questioniare (content) via ajax call on a mvc 3 page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a list of questions and I want to save user answers via an ajax call. For example I have 50 questions not sure if I need to loop thru all 50 question and send each answer to a controller (save) or its possible to send results as large data to a controller.

my view:

```
@using COPSGMIS;
@model IEnumerable<COPSGMIS.Models.Quiz>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Questionaire";
}
<h2>Questionaire</h2>
  <input type="hidden" id="currentstep" name="currentstep" />
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Questionaire", "Question", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SignupForm" }))
   {
       <div id="wizardtemplate">       
            @foreach (var step in Model)       
            {
              <fieldset class="wizard">
                <div class="page_Title"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => step.Title)</div>               
                @foreach (var question in step.Results)
                {
                ... code removed ....
                <label for="question">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => question.NumberedQuestion)</label>  
                 @Html.Raw(Html.DisplayControl(question.QuestionID, question.Choices, question.AnswerValue,question.ControlType)) 
                 </div>                               
                 @Html.Partial("_Comment", question)
               <hr />
                }
              </fieldset>
            }
```

HTML rendered:

```
<label for="question">3. This is a sample question (2) for the questionare?</label>  
                 <div class='answer'><input type='date' id='3' name='3' value='2012-12-10' /></div> 
                 </div>                               
 ... code removed ....

 <label for="question">4. This is a sample question (3) for the questionare?</label>  
                 <div class='answer'><input type='text' id='4' name='4' value='999' /></div> 
                 </div>
```

Model:

```
 public class Quiz
    {
        public int ReviewID { get; set; }
        public int StepID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Result> Results { get; set; }
    }
```

ajax call:

```
function SaveAnswer(//not sure what needs to be passed) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Question/SaveQuestionaire',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: ({
            // not sure what this will look like?
        }),
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (json) {
            // Message to confirm save
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ease of use, it would be easy to send an AJAX request for every single question.  However, you should be able to push up an array of entries to the server, and interpret it as an array of objects.

You can build an array like so:

```
var array = [];

for (var i = 0; ...)
   array.push(items[i]);
```

Then push the array to the server.

Since you are building a large form, you could also try doing:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/Question/SaveQuestionaire',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $("#SignupForm").serialize(), // creates an object for you
```

But for that to work, you have to be careful of the ID's it generates, as this is used to recreate the object array.  Not sure if the approach you took accomodates that.

Comment: Can you give me an example how I would grab all question and send them as an array? Would I need to loop  thru all questions via Jquery and build the array?

Comment: One last question, in the array if I want to include ids along with the data? How would that work

Comment: Why would you include the ID's in the arrays?  What purpose would that serve?  Also, I updated my example above, if you didn't see.  You can build an object in JSON notation like { response: 'yes', name: 'bob smith' } and push these objects into the array, then push the array to the server, or simply post the entire contents of the form to the server.

Comment: I need the ids because I need to associate the answers with the questions. I am saving questionId along with the answers.

Comment: I think I will serialize the form: data: $("#SignupForm").serialize(). How would unserialize and loop thru the form data in the controller?

Comment: That's probably the best bet.  To be honest, I'm not sure.  You can examine how MVC does send this to the controller by having your action accept FormCollection.  This is a generic key/value collection, which you can study the form response a little better.